# Is there any efficient method on how to get id of object to my create method

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I am creating a web module, and want to get ID of table licensing level two parse into my create method. Hence each ID of level will have a task and the ID need to be stored within my licensing table as a foreign key which reflects ID in Level Two table. How could I solve this, anyone can give me a good suggestion or way on doing this

```
 public function add_show($id) 
    { 
        $level = PreLicensingLevelTwo::where('id', $id)->first(); 
        $level->prelicensingtask  = PreLicensingTask::where('pre_licensing_level_two_id', $level->id)->with('staff', 'statusdesc', 'prelicensingtaskstaff')->get();
        return view('staff.regulatory.statutory.approval.display',compact('level')); 
    }

    public function create()
{   
    $staff = Staff::pluck('staff_name'); 
    $status = PreLicensingStatus::pluck('status_description', 'id');
    return view('staff.regulatory.statutory.approval.create', compact('staff','status'));
}

public function show($id)
{
     $one = PreLicensingLevelOne::where('pre_licensing_main_id', $id)->get();
     foreach ($one as $key => $license) 
     {
        $license->two = PreLicensingLevelTwo::where('pre_licensing_level_one_id', $license->id)->get();
     }
     $rendered = view('staff.regulatory.statutory.approval.show')->with('one', $one)->render();
     return response()->json(array('status' => 1, 'tableData' => $rendered));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> With help from my working collegue this is how i able to solve the question i asked

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'task_title' => 'required', 
        'task_description' => 'required', 
        'task_due_date' => 'required', 
     ]);

     $leveltwo = PreLicensingLevelTwo::find($request->input('pre_licensing_level_two_id'));

     $prelicensingtask = new PreLicensingTask; 
     $prelicensingtask->task_title =$request->input('task_title'); 
     $prelicensingtask->task_description =$request->input('task_description'); 
     $prelicensingtask->task_due_date =$request->input('task_due_date');
     $prelicensingtask->created_by_staff_id = Auth::user()->ref_user->staff_id;
     $prelicensingtask->status = $request->input('status');
     $prelicensingtask->pre_licensing_level_two_id = $leveltwo->id;
     $prelicensingtask->pre_licensing_level_one_id = $leveltwo->pre_licensing_level_one_id;
     $prelicensingtask->pre_licensing_main_id = $leveltwo->pre_licensing_main_id;
     $prelicensingtask->centre_id = Auth::user()->ref_user->centre_id;
     $prelicensingtask->save(); 
     return redirect()->back();

}
```